# How to get details of the public key generated using Laravel Passport?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, jwk, krakend

I am trying to create an endpoint that returns details about the public key so that an API gateway like Krakend uses these details to verify the JWT. The endpoint needs to return response similar to the following json response.

```
{
   "keys":[
      {
         "alg":"RS256",
         "kty":"RSA",
         "use":"sig",
         "n":"5dfikb_OwXGysznPX5Z4lcdXTGTmcDpBu4P_IYf9agP71NpVLF3nGnhedJGbiAk6hC6PMtrh7slURD6CWSgIjpvxemyXrPeSIlmpG068TKYHzFjYrJKou-Z1YbYGepRtKhepktN65vMPnqbMpqMrZKoY12dzPuD7EVHjvoQQ2EZ7K3TqMyPFm3MS7hYp8cL0CpSd1Tz40CEKY6l-WorCYbc7ULIMdAeiAlPesllerqzSc3MIkq9RKGrcbg-qWWEumxsdVG0nh-sI1q8UL_ctx1LB3yrF9F2gyLvsWIPDPfObP9zv40XcuALr83NwroofkeRLcP1jjoEvX-BN6Dyzdw",
         "e":"AQAB",
         "kid":"MDNGMjU2M0U3RERFQUEwOUUzQUMwQ0NBN0Y1RUY0OEIxNTRDM0IxMw",
         "x5t":"MDNGMjU2M0U3RERFQUEwOUUzQUMwQ0NBN0Y1RUY0OEIxNTRDM0IxMw",
         "x5c":[
            "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"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I have generated the Public and Private keys by running the Laravel Passport keys command

```
php artisan passport:keys
```

Comment: *The endpoint needs to return response similar to the following json response* - that's a JSON Web Key Set (JWKS), containing keys in JWK format. You can read [this](https://www.tuxed.net/fkooman/blog/json_web_key_set.html) as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you @jps . The article helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the keys in storage folder of your project.

```
oauth-private.key
oauth-public.key
```

[image]